# Code to set alert for new high of day and new low of day?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to figure out how to write a script that will give me alerts when there is a new high of day and a new low of day.

```
day_high = na
day_low = na
booleanhigh = false
booleanlow = false

if is_first and barstate.isnew
    day_high := high
    day_low := low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]
if high > day_high
    day_high := high
    booleanhigh := true
if low < day_low
    day_low := low
    booleanlow := true
alertcondition(booleanhigh, "High of Day Alert", "New HOD")
alertcondition(booleanlow, "Low of Day Alert", "New LOD")
```

this gives me the repainting error for the alert condition, and it is a study, would this work?

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is a warning rather than an error.

You can add `barstate.isconfirmed` to your alert condition or select *Once Per Bar Close* option when you are creating your alert if you don't want your alerts to repaint.

> **barstate.isconfirmed:** Returns true if the script is calculating the last (closing) update of the current bar. The next script calculation
> will be on the new bar data.

[image]